# Автоматическая печать страницы в IE

Tags: javascript, печать, кроссбраузерность

Доброго всем времени суток господа

```
// внутри боди прописываю скрипт, т.к. в боди прописывать не вариант в моем случае
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = print;
</script>
```

Собственно, пользуюсь данным кодом, что позволяет при загрузке страницы увидеть окно для печати. И как это обычно бывает под IE9 не работает. Можете ли подсказать почему?

p.s. данное же решение брал с хэшкода в ответах (нагуглил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.onload = function() {
   print('');
   void(0);
}
```

м?

Comment: да. оно самое. теперь вооружусь этим. спасибо

Comment: можно и без void